# Couldn't pass observable to another component from one in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components:
*change-request-details.component* within which is the *edit-change-request-details-dialog.component*.
I am attempting to pass an object of Observable type from change-request-details.component to the edit-change-request-details-dialog.component.
In the change-request-details.component.ts(the parent), I have defined this variable :

```
result$: Observable<ChangeRequest>;
```

Which gets assigned an Obervable inside the ngOnInit()  this way:

```
this.result$ = this._projectRequestService.findByChangeId(this.changeId);
```

In my child component, the edit-change-request-details-dialog.component, I am attempting to retrieve this way:

```
@Input() result$: Observable<ChangeRequest>;
ngOnInit(): void {
    /*
    this.result$
      .pipe(tap((temp) => (this.changeRequest = temp)))
      .subscribe();
    */
   /*
    this.result$
      .pipe(
        tap((data: ChangeRequest) => {
          this.changeRequest = data;
          console.log('selectedChangeRequest inside function', this.changeRequest);
        })
      )
    */
    this.result$.subscribe((resp) => {
      this.changeRequest = resp;
      console.log('details', this.changeRequest);
    });
    
  }
```

All of the three methods of have failed and in the console(F12), I can see the following error message:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at EditChangeRequestDetailsDialogComponent.ngOnInit (edit-change-request-details-dialog.component.ts:75)
    at callHook (core.js:3038)
    at callHooks (core.js:3008)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2960)
    at refreshView (core.js:7187)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8281)
    at refreshView (core.js:7196)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8327)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:6965)
    at refreshView (core.js:7222)
```

When I was using pipe as in the other methods the error message said the property 'pipe' is undefined.

I couldn’t understand as to why it gives me an error. Can you help by letting me know how I can pass an Object  from one component to another.
Thank you.

Comment: your `this._projectRequestService.findByChangeId(this.changeId);` return an observable?

Comment: It should, because I defined it this way:
    findByChangeId(changeReqId: string): Observable<ChangeRequest> {
      return this._http
        .get<ChangeRequest>(`/api/v1/changes/cr/${changeReqId}`)
        .pipe(shareReplay());
    }

Comment: try make a getter in the input and subscribe to it

Answer (score 1):

you can try subscribe in the getter of the Input not in ngOnInit

```
@Input() get result$(value: Observable<ChangeRequest>){
  value.subscribe((resp) => {
      this.changeRequest = resp;
      console.log('details', this.changeRequest);
    });
} ;
```